# How to add Microsoft Word option to the mouse right-click drop-down menu in internet explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, windows-7, ms-office, add-in

I have the Windows 7 home basic OS (64-bit) with an internet explorer 11. My computer is Dell Inspiron 5520, i5.

When you select some text, like a sentence or word in internet explorer and right-click on your mouse you get the option of sending the selected item to Microsoft OneNote directly. Right? How do I send the same selected text directly to a notepad, WordPad or even a MS Word file directly? How can I add that option also to the drop-down menu which appears after the mouse right-click?

I had a live chat with a Microsoft technical support personal. He was unable to provide a solution. Hence I am asking it here. Please help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question should probably be migrated to superuser.com?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Gregor. I shall also do that